How to Identify the Flow ID for Power Automate Approvals via API?
I’m working on an application where I need to fetch all Power Automate approvals associated with specific flows. For example, I have three different flows, and each one has its own approvals. The challenge is that while I’m using an API to retrieve all approvals, I cannot determine which flow each approval belongs to.
How can I identify the flow ID or determine which flow an approval is associated with? Is there a specific API endpoint or method to achieve this?
Any guidance or examples would be appreciated.
I am currently using the following API to fetch approvals in my spfx web part:
https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/{env-id}/approvalViews?$filter=properties/userRole+eq+'Approver'+and+properties/isActive+eq+'true'

below is the code example:
const getApprovalData = async (): Promise<IApproval[]> => {
    const accessToken = await tokenService.getAccessToken();
    try {
      const url = `https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/${environmentId}/approvalViews?$filter=properties/userRole+eq+'Approver'+and+properties/isActive+eq+'true'`;
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      console.log(accessToken);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      return data.value.map((item: any) => ({
        id: item.name,
        title: item.properties.title,
        status: 'Pending',
        assignedTo: item.properties.principals[0]?.displayName || 'N/A',
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching approvals: ', error);
      return [];
    }
  };

